# Filtering Duplicates after UNION

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables: `Activities` & `Edited` they are pretty the same but `Edited` contains a few additional columns that allow me to process data offline. The record may be at one of the tables or in both.

I need to take a bunch of data that will contain only a unique `activityKey`. The latest result should be based on `editDate`. For example:

```
SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted
FROM activities
WHERE projectID = '4'  
AND deleted = 0
UNION
SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted
FROM edited
WHERE projectID = '4' 
ORDER BY editDate DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

[image]

But It only collects the data from both tables. And I get duplications like in the screenshot: `WO-981` & `WO-924`.
Question:
How I can remove these duplicates and use only the newest records based on `editDate`.
Also, I need to remove the record if `deleted = 1` at `editDate` and `deleted = 0` at `activities` table as with `WO-924` it should be removed.

Comment: This part : *I need to remove the record if deleted = 1 at editDate and deleted = 0 at activities table as with WO-924 it should be removed* is not clear. Better post expected results to clarify. Also do you mean *...if deleted = 1 at edited...*?

Comment: show the schema with primary key

Comment: @Uomolepre unfortunately we don't use primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this, if `deleted` takes on only the values of 0 and 1:

```
SELECT activityKey, editDate,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN deleted = 0 THEN editDate END) = MAX(editDate)
             THEN 0 ELSE 1
        END) as deleted
FROM (SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted
      FROM activities
      WHERE projectID = '4' AND deleted = 0
      UNION ALL
      SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted
      FROM edited
      WHERE projectID = '4' 
     ) ae
GROUP BY activityKey
ORDER BY MAX(editDate) DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

The more general solution is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, but this works for this case.

EDIT:

If you want to skip rows with `deleted` = 1, then add the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT activityKey, editDate,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN deleted = 0 THEN editDate END) = MAX(editDate)
             THEN 0 ELSE 1
        END) as deleted
FROM (SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted
      FROM activities
      WHERE projectID = '4' AND deleted = 0
      UNION ALL
      SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted
      FROM edited
      WHERE projectID = '4' 
     ) ae
GROUP BY activityKey
HAVING MAX(editDate) = MAX(CASE WHEN deleted = 1 THEN editDate END)
ORDER BY MAX(editDate) DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: You are right it works well! I get all that I want except one thing. How I may skip records with `delete 1` after that transformation that you have done?

Comment: I tried to add: `SELECT activityKey, editDate, deleted FROM (your selection) WHERE delete = 0` but it returns only 1 row 

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss . . . Perhaps the first 20 rows returned by the query have only one undeleted value.  To skip values, you can use a `HAVING` clause.